# How to solve- "<Something> is already declared in the upper scope" code smells?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, eslint

I am getting following code smell in my sonarqube dashboard, and I am not sure how to resolve such issues.

> 'isInitialized' is already declared in the upper scope.

Here's my code-

```
let _isInitialized = false;

/**
 * Getter for _isInitialized
 *
 * @return {Boolean} _isInitialized
 */
export const isInitialized = function() {
    return _isInitialized;
};

/**
 * Sets isInitialized
 * @param {Boolean} isInitialized new value for inititialized
 */
export const setIsInitialized = function( isInitialized ) {
    _isInitialized = isInitialized;
};
```

Can anyone please explain what's the problem in my code?

Don't know what to try as my code is working correctly but getting this issue on sonarqube dashboard.

Comment: Which version of eslint are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you define a variable called `isInitialized` in the scope of the module using `const`

> ```
> export const isInitialized = function() {
> ```

---

Here you define a variable **with the same name** in the scope of the function using an argument name.

> ```
> export const setIsInitialized = function( isInitialized ) {
> ```

---

Don't do that. Use unique names for variables.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: There isn't any problem with the code.

---

SonarQube is configured to check a rule similar to the [`no-shadow`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow) rule of ESLint. It basically checks that the code does not reuse a name when another object is accessible in the same scope using that name.

The function `setIsInitialized()` uses the name `isInitialized` for its parameter but in its scope, the global const `isInitialized` is also visible.
The function parameter `isInitialized` hides the global const, rendering it unusable in the function body.

Your current code:

```js
let _isInitialized = false;

export const isInitialized = function() {    -- this is not available here --+
    return _isInitialized;                                                   |
};                                                                           |
                                                                             |
export const setIsInitialized = function( isInitialized ) {     \            |
    _isInitialized = isInitialized;             ^                | <-------- +
};                         |                    |               /
                           +-- this is this ----+
```

You can rename the parameter of `setIsInitialized()` to have access to the global const `isInitialized` and this will make the message disappear.

```js
let _isInitialized = false;

export const isInitialized = function() {
    return _isInitialized;
};

export const setIsInitialized = function( initialized ) {
    _isInitialized = initialized;
};
```

Your code does not need this change because the `setIsInitialized()` function does not have any reason to use the `isInitialized()` function.

However, avoiding shadowing is generally considered a good practice; it prevents confusion and misunderstanding for the code readers.